# Error at login PhpMyAdmin on VPS OVH(ubuntu 16.04) with NGINX

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, phpmyadmin

I have a strange problem with my (nginx/phpmyadmin) setting

ubuntu version 16.04 LTS Server 
nginx version 1.10.0
php version 7
MariaDB version 10.1.14-MariaDB-1~xenial - mariadb.org binary distribution
phpmyadmin version 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu1

I can access to login page of phpmyadmin via : http://vpsXXX.vps.ovh.ca/phpmyadmin

I enter username root and his password and login

I receive a 404 error because the login process erase "phpmyadmin" from my path so I obtain something like this : http://vpsXXX.vps.ovh.ca/index.php?token=...............

If i manually insert between ...ovh.ca/phpmyadmin/index?token=.....
It's working fine...

So how can resolve this path problem

this is my "default" ngnix config file : /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

    location /phpmyadmin {
        index index.php;
    }

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php7.0-cgi alone:
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php7.0-fpm:
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

This is my VHOSTS files : /var/www/vhosts/skwad.me/conf/ngnix.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/vhosts/skwad.me/html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name skwad.me www.skwad.me;

    access_log /var/www/vhosts/skwad.me/logs/access_log;
    error_log /var/www/vhosts/skwad.me/logs/error_log;

    location / 
    {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html 
    {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

# Pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server #  
location ~ \.php$ 
{
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your helping !

Comment: Have you tried setting [this](https://phpmyadmin-english-united-kingdom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri)

Comment: Is not working, with change the settings : $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://vps80XXX.vps.ovh.ca/phpmyadmin/'  i not see the login page...